# HMGET and correlation beetwen number of fields and reading performance

Tags: performance, redis

Have some question about HMGET performance.

Can you explain how number of fields in hash affect reading performance?

Example 1. 20000 requests. HMGET with 4 fields. Commands in pipeline. Hash contains 760 fields
On test machine it takes about 1500ms.

Example 2. 20000 requests. HMGET with 4 fields. Commands in pipeline. Hash contains 30 fields
On test machine it takes about 300ms.

Comment: Look at the `hash-max-ziplist-entries` and `hash-max-ziplist-value` - these control the internal encoding threshold of Hashes, between the faster-but-more-RAM-consuming ziplist to the slower-but-smaller dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be O(1) in both cases - independent of the number of fields in the hash. So 5x the time for 20x the number of keys sounds excessive.

I tried to replicate and got very consistent performance. Here what I did:

Created three hashes, with 10, 1000, 100000 fields each:

```
> EVAL "for i=1,10 do redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], i, i) end" 1 Test1HMGET
(nil)
> EVAL "for i=1,1000 do redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], i, i) end" 1 Test2HMGET
(nil)
> EVAL "for i=1,100000 do redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], i, i) end" 1 Test3HMGET
(nil)
> HLEN Test1HMGET
(integer) 10
> HLEN Test2HMGET
(integer) 1000
> HLEN Test3HMGET
(integer) 100000
```

Then run [`redis-benchmark`](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) to test HMGET:

```
$ redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test1HMGET 4 6 7 9
HMGET Test1HMGET 4 6 7 9: 8841.73 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test2HMGET 4 6 7 9
HMGET Test2HMGET 4 6 7 9: 8788.89 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test3HMGET 4 6 7 9
HMGET Test3HMGET 4 6 7 9: 8863.68 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test3HMGET 45 667 567 56789
HMGET Test3HMGET 45 667 567 56789: 8819.51 requests per second
```

As shown, regardless of the hash length, it consistently got ~8800 rps.

Other commands, like HGETALL, do show a decline.

```
$ redis-benchmark -n 20000 -c 1 -q HGETALL Test1HMGET
HGETALL Test1HMGET: 7840.06 requests per second
$ redis-benchmark -n 20000 -c 1 -q HGETALL Test2HMGET
HGETALL Test2HMGET: 600.08 requests per second
```

There must be something else on your test driving the difference you observe, perhaps payload difference if you are using different fields.

**Update**: As pointed out by the OP, there is a performance difference once you get close to `hash-max-ziplist-entries`. See [Antirez article](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization), and [this post](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/understanding-redis-hash-max-ziplist-entries). Your average read performance decay, due to compression. It is a CPU / memory trade-off.

On my machine, I had `max-ziplist-entries` = 512. Performance is 2.3x slower towards the end of the key-space. Once we go over the compression optimization threshold (514 fields), it is constant across the key-space, but memory usage went up 6.6x.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar test to @LeoMurillo did.

```
redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test1HMGET 1 2 3 4
HMGET Test1HMGET 1 2 3 4: 26648.90 requests per second

redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test1HMGET 10 9 8 7
HMGET Test1HMGET 10 9 8 7: 26267.40 requests per second

redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test2HMGET 1 2 3 4
HMGET Test2HMGET 1 2 3 4: 26737.97 requests per second

redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test2HMGET 1000 999 998 997
HMGET Test2HMGET 1000 999 998 997: 11201.97 requests per second

redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test3HMGET 1 2 3 4
HMGET Test3HMGET 1 2 3 4: 27514.10 requests per second

redis-benchmark -n 200000 -c 1 -q HMGET Test3HMGET 100000 99999 99998 99997
HMGET Test3HMGET 100000 99999 99998 99997: 27311.21 requests per second
```

Then I checked *hash-max-ziplist-entries*. It is set to 1500.
So in my case *Test1HMGET* and *Test2HMGET* have *encoding:ziplist*, and *Test3HMGET* *encoding:hashtable*.

So I think it is all about compression. When a hashset is compressed, getting fields from the end of a set is so much slower.